# R - mutate with regex in a loop

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a data frame in which every column consists of number followed by text, e.g. *533 234r/r*.

The following code to get rid off text works well:

```
  my_data <- my_data %>%
    mutate(column1 = str_extract(column1, '.+?(?=[a-z])'))
```

I would like to do it for multiple columns:

```
col_names <- names(my_data)
for (i in 1:length(col_names)) {
  my_data <- my_data%>%
    mutate(col_names[i] = str_extract(col_names[i], '.+?(?=[a-z])'))
}
```

But it returns an error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  my_data <- my_data %>%
    mutate(col_names[i] ="
```

I think *mutate_all()* wouldn't work as well, bcos *str_extract()* requires column name as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using strings, then convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) while we do the assignment with (`:=`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
col_names <- names(my_data)
for (i in seq_along(col_names)) {
  my_data <- my_data   %>%
          mutate(!! col_names[i] := 
            str_extract(!!rlang::sym(col_names[i]), '.+?(?=[a-z])'))
       }
```

---

In `tidyverse`, we could do this with `across` instead of looping with a `for` loop (`dplyr` version `>= 1.0`)

```
my_data <- my_data %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_extract(., '.+?(?=[a-z])')))
```

If the `dplyr` version is old, use `mutate_all`

```
my_data <- my_data %>%
          mutate_all(~ str_extract(., '.+?(?=[a-z])'))
```